# Quick and dirty duplicate finder based on size and last write time only

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, hash, duplicates

Is there a simple and **fast** python code to identify duplicate files in a directory tree based on **filesize and last write time only**? (A couple false positives are OK. Forget hash, too slow and not needed to initial ID of potential real dups.)

S/O abounds with similar questions but they tend to utilize md5 or byte-by-byte comparison.

Any suggestions? Or, I need to run the code below and compare to find dup lines in the first two columns? (And maybe run hash only on the ones with matching LWT and size)?

```
def get_size(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return str(st.st_size)

def get_last_write_time(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    convert_time_to_human_readable = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
    return convert_time_to_human_readable
```

Comment: Correct, so far that's is my best bet. I am wondering if there is a build in module in python or a code which compares the size, LWT and **only** hashes files matching those values, or other solutions...

Comment: Why are you looking at the last write time? If I make a file with "eggs" in it, then ten minutes later another file with "eggs", they are still duplicates, even if the modification time differs by ten minutes.

Comment: You are correct, they are duplicates. I agree the size alone could be a quick way to check. But in real life, it is rare to re-create the same exact files, and LWT adds an other layer of filter. Try it out on your work/personal files and see how unique the LWT and sizes really are. Very much in my experience, although I do have examples when different files share same LWT and size.  If you dump the .ext in the quick check, then it is even more stringent

Comment: hi again, try this one! ... will check duplicates in a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*LOL! Thats my code! :)))))))*

Try This ( **LAST UPDATE** ):

```
import os, hashlib, time

your_target_folder = "." # change with your target folder.


def size_check(get_path):

    try:
        st = os.stat(get_path)
    except:
        return "Error"

    else:
        return str(st.st_size)


def md5_check(get_path):

    try:
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(get_path, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)
    except:
        return "Error"
    else:
        return hash_md5.hexdigest()


def save_data(get_output):

    with open("./data.txt", 'a') as output_data:
        output_data.write(get_output)



print("Waking On All Files In Your Target Directory and Grabbing Their Personal Hashes, Plz Wait ... \n")

files_and_sizes = {}
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(your_target_folder):

    for items in filenames:

        file_full_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, items))
        get_size = size_check(file_full_path)

        if get_size in files_and_sizes:
            files_and_sizes[get_size].append(file_full_path)

        else:
            files_and_sizes[get_size] = [file_full_path]


new_dict = {}
error_box = []

for key, box_name in files_and_sizes.items():

    if not key == "Error" and len(box_name) > 1:

        for files in box_name:

            get_file_hash = md5_check(files)

            if not get_file_hash == "Error":

                if get_file_hash in new_dict:
                    new_dict[get_file_hash].append(files)

                else:
                    new_dict[get_file_hash] = [files]

            else:
                error_box.append(files)

    elif key == "Error" and len(box_name) > 0:

        do = [error_box.append(error_files) for error_files in box_name]

    else:
        pass


for hashes, names in new_dict.items():

    if len(names) > 1:

        for each_files in names:

            result = each_files + "\n"
            print(result)
            save_data(result)

    else:
        pass

if len(error_box) > 0:
    print("Something Went Wrong On These Files ( I could not access them ): " + str(error_box) + "\n")


print("Good By.")
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Thanks! I am trying but: Where in the `main.py` I am inserting `dupi.py`? Is there anything else to change in the `main.py` in order to see it working?

Comment: @HakariDo: did you read my explanation? you should coy+paste that class in dupi.py, then import dupi in any kind of your .py file with that method! may tick me plz with +1? :)

Comment: i will definitely tick you, but let's make it work first.  now i have dupi.py and main.py in the same folder. then i run main.py as it is. getting error: `line 6 ModuleNotFoundError No modul named dupi.`

Comment: @HakariDo: check uppercases Dupi, or dupi ( file name )? and you import dupi or Dupi? they should be same! and did you change sys.path.append('Dupi_folder_address like "." ') to sys.path.append(".")?

Comment: dupi.py and main.py are in the same dir. main.py: `    `sys.path.append(".")
    from dupi import *` getting error

Comment: @HakariDo: this is not about python, something wrong in your paths or file names, plz add a update title to your question and put your codes ( not my original codes! ) in update box and take a screenshot from your folder, or just take a screen shot.

Comment: @HakariDo: i will check it.

Comment: why do not you edit the code in your answer exactly as it should be, so we can move ahead with troubleshooting. lets use lowercase dupi and enter the dir name so both main and dupi.py are in the same folder

Comment: @HakariDo: "ModuleNotFoundError No modul named dupi" means no such file or directory ... what should i do with my code?! it means sys.apppend works but "import" could not find dupi.py, its about your paths! but ok i will update my answer ... now..just a minute plz.

Comment: @HakariDo: check my update.

Comment: now seems the two files are communicating, but getting error on line 19 in main.py and line 15 and 29 in dupi.py

Comment: you have some special errors on your ENVV paths! and i do not know why! ok do not use it as module! just use it as class ... i will detele my other codes. check it again.

Comment: errors lines 15, 29, 47 in updated file.

Comment: @HakariDo: what are the error messages?!

Comment: ` get_data = make_object.check_files()
first_file = get_size(self.path_1) + self.salt + get_last_write_time(self.path_1)
    st = os.stat(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:`

Comment: @HakariDo: commmmee onn mannn!!! did you check this line : CheckDuplicates("your_first_file_address", "your_second_file_address", your_salt)?? you should replace your own file address with them!!

Comment: the question was how i can check duplicates in a directory. so where i am entering the path to that directory? so far i assumed the script would work in the cwd. not clear what two files you are asking for.

Comment: can you just make it simple and work in the cwd for now?

Comment: @HakariDo: so in this case please update/edit your question, because i can not file "check duplicates in a directory" sentence in your question. and i will answer you.

Comment: what is your code doing? compares two files if they are dups? finds dups in a directory? something else?

Comment: @HakariDo: compares two files, if they were duplicate return [file1 hash , file2 hash, "DUPLICATE"] and if they were not return [file1 hash, file2 hash, "DIFFERENT"] . that hash is a personal hash ( mix LWT,size, size )

Comment: I think there was a miscommunication. Question was aimed how to find duplicate files very quickly from a set of files (e.g, from a folder or folders), not checking if two stand-alone files are dups or not. iupvote is done, but i am still waiting for the right answer.

Comment: @HakariDo: hi again, try this one! ... will check duplicates in a directory.

Comment: @HakariDo: did you check that?

Comment: OK, now the code runs smoothly. But doesn't it calculate the md5 for every files? Any way it can export all duplicate files into a duplicates.txt in the CWD?

Comment: @HakariDo: man it dose not calc md5!!! it is a personal hash with LWT and file_size! you wana to save dupi files in a tetx file? ok i will update it.

Comment: what do you means "personal hash"?

Comment: @HakariDo: updated, just try it again.

Comment: can you explain what this code does? i see md5, are you calculating it? also, in the output text, can you please have each duplicate files listed as a new line?

Comment: @HakariDo: it does not clac the md5 of each files, it calc mdf of "LWT + FILE_SIZE" of each files ( calc string md5 not file md5, muuchhh faster and efficient ) ! i recommend you  to do not save dupi files as new line! why?! if you have four dupi files and another four dupi files, these are two lists, if you save them as new line how you could detect wich file with wich file are dupi?! for example A and B are dupi, C and D are another dupi but differnet from A and B! you save them as new line, how you want to detect or understand A with B are dupi or B with C are dupi?!!

Comment: @HakariDo: you should save each lists as new line [A, B] on first line and [C, D] on second line, now you can understand ...

Comment: i"t calc md5 of "LWT + FILE_SIZE" of each files"  why calculating md5 of the LWTand size is better than simply comparing the `[LWTsize]` digits? you actually eliminating information content by doing that.  **The ideal program would  do this:** compare each file's [LWTsize] within a dir tree, **then** for only those files whose [LWTsize] is identical calculate the true file md5 or byte-by-byte. This would be very useful, and not far from your code. If you do it you are accepted as best answer.

Comment: @HakariDo: "then for only those files whose [LWTsize] is identical calculate the true file md5 or byte-by-byte" you mean if they were same, i should comparing their md5? right? so... how should i save that result? save each files as new line? or save each lists as new line?

Comment: lets make simpler: 1. get only the size for all files. 2. compare size. 3. eliminate all unique size files. 4. on the remaining set of files (the ones whose size occurs more than once = possible dups) do an md5 or byte-by-bytes comparison. 5.  print out the dup paths as a new line each. i think that would be very handy.

Comment: @HakariDo: done. try it again...

Comment: can you please make the output line by line (every duplicate fullpath/file.ext is a **new line**)?  i need to compare your result to my other (slow) duplicate finder programs. also can you explain the logic behind this? it compare sizes then md5? thank you!

Comment: @HakariDo: ok i will upadte it again!, yes it compare sizes then md5... ( i did not see this line : "print out the dup paths as a new line each." )

Comment: @HakariDo: Done. check it ...

Comment: @HakariDo: is it ok?

Comment: looks very nice on initial testing, thnak you very much!

Comment: DRPK: if you have time, here is another Q, you seem to be good at this:
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211331](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211331/os-rename-per-string-in-dir-name-and-fileextension-lookup-table))