# os.rename per string in dir name and fileextension (lookup table)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having trouble calling keys and values from lookup table to rename files. The task:

- in CWD, find each dir that **ends** `=camID` (e.g, ...=d5), then
- find `raw_file` inside `=camID`, then
- prefix all `raw_file` filenames (but not other filenames) with `device_name`.

**Code**:

```
for camID in config:
    if dir_name.endswith(camID):
        for filename in os.listdir(camID):
            if filename.endswith(config(nested(raw_file))):
                os.rename(filename, config(nested(cam_name)){}_{}filename)
```

**Lookup**:

```
config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
}
config['g7']['cam_name'] = 'Canon-G7'
config['g7']['raw_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')

config['d5']['cam_name'] = 'Nikon-D5'
config['d5']['raw_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')

#'g7', 'd5' are called "camID"
```

Tree **before** and **after**:

```
CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/ .nef,.jpg,.avi,.wav
    02_camdirxyz=g7                     
          /bbb/ddd/ .cr2,.jpg,.mp4
    04_camdire012345                     
          / .mp4,.jpg,.avi

CWD                                      
    01_camdirab=d5                       
          /aaa/ Nikon-D5_.nef, Nikon-D5_.jpg, Nikon-D5_.avi, .wav         
    02_camdirxyz=g7                      
          /bbb/ddd/ Canon-G7_.cr2, Canon-G7_.jpg, Canon-G7_.mp4              
    04_camdire012345                     
          /.mp4,.jpg,.avi
```

Comment: `for filename in camID:` means you iterate over the string camID, for example "g7". This will give you "g" and "7" as the items. Use `os.listdir` on camID instead, to iterate over the actual content of the folder.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code (see OP) and tried out but getting the `os.rename(filename, config(device_name){}_{}filename)` syntax error. Any hints how to fix calling it from the lookup table?

Comment: `for os.listdir in camID:` should be more like `for filename in os.listdir(camID):`. The way you did it, the function `os.listidir` is the loop variable and is therefore overwritten with a new value for each run of the loop. You can always quick-test a line of code in the Python interactive shell when in doubt how a function works or what a loop acutally does. Also, little debug prints inside your code might help you to help yourself.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the code in OP, but still getting error at the `{}_{}` in the last line. I think I call the nested key values incorrectly.

Comment: @HakariDo: you want to rename all raw_file files in your current directory ( with that special key_word at end ) and its subdirectory to device_name? right?

Comment: Append the `cam_name` as a prefix_ to the filename for all `raw_files` that are present in the directories ending with the corresponding `=camID` key.  So we start with `DSC100.jpg` and get `Nikon-D5_DSC100.jpg`, for example.  See the before and after panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kinda hacky, but here's what works on that setup:

```
import os

config = {
    'g7': {},
    'd5': {},
}
config['g7']['cam_name'] = 'Canon-G7'
config['g7']['raw_file'] = ('cr2', 'jpg', 'mp4')

config['d5']['cam_name'] = 'Nikon-D5'
config['d5']['raw_file'] = ('nef', 'jpg', 'avi')

root = "test"

for camID in config:
    for dir in next(os.walk(root))[1]:
        if dir.lower().endswith(camID):
            for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(root, dir)):
                for f in files:
                    if any([f.lower().endswith(x) for x in config[camID]["raw_file"]]):
                        os.rename(os.path.join(path, f), 
                                  os.path.join(path, "%s_%s" % (config[camID]['cam_name'], f)))
```

Please note the usage of `os.walk()` to get directories only, and then using it again to recursively walking through the whole subdirectory.

As a result, I have this as a starting point:

```
# find test
test
test/.jpg
test/04_camdire012345
test/04_camdire012345/.avi
test/04_camdire012345/.jpg
test/04_camdire012345/.mp4
test/02_camdirxyz=g7
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd/.mp4
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd/.jpg
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd/.cr2
test/01_camdirab=d5
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/.wav
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/.avi
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/.jpg
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/.nef
```

And after running the code:

```
# find test
test
test/.jpg
test/04_camdire012345
test/04_camdire012345/.avi
test/04_camdire012345/.jpg
test/04_camdire012345/.mp4
test/02_camdirxyz=g7
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd/Canon-G7.cr2
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd/Canon-G7.jpg
test/02_camdirxyz=g7/bbb/ddd/Canon-G7.mp4
test/01_camdirab=d5
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/Nikon-D5.nef
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/Nikon-D5.jpg
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/Nikon-D5.avi
test/01_camdirab=d5/aaa/.wav
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. A bonus Q: How can I make it case insensitive (so it will treat jpg JPG nef NEF the same)?  what would be the proper use of `lowercase`?

Comment: one issue: the code does not include an underscore `_` between the cam_name and filename so the result would be `Nikon-D5_origfile.jpg`.  I am trying this, does not work `os.path.join(path, "%s%s" % (config[camID]['timezone'], '_', f)))`. suggestions?

Comment: underscore `_` fixed: `os.path.join(path, "%s%s%s" % (config[camID]['cam_name'], "_", f)))`. how i make the extensions case-insensitive?

Comment: Fixed the underscore

Comment: Case sensitivity fixed